# why Application_Error can not handlle some errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

i developed a website(MVC 5) and upload it on a iis7 on a web server.
i handle errors on method

```
protected void Application_Error(){}
```

on the Global.asax.
yesterday i did some tests on it and i saw when i enter this url

```
http://www.xxxx.com/.
```

i can get invalid rout on Application_Error method but when i entered that URL with 3dotes or more like this URL

```
http://www.xxxx.com/...
```

i saw a webpage with this content and Application_Error not works because i have no default page or view with this content on my project.

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

i did some test on another website on the internet and i saw some of theme has the same issue and i think i should do some config on my IIS.

if yes , what config(s) i should set on my IIS and if no what i can do with my project until i can handle it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this configuration in the **web.config** file:

```
   <customErrors mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="URL">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="URL" />
      <error statusCode="402" redirect="URL" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="URL" />
   </customErrors>
```

**Example**: 

I created a ***ErrorHandlerController*** with the following ActionResult's:

```
//This action return a view that show the http error you specified.
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}

//This action return a view that show the 404 http error captured.
public ActionResult NotFoud()
{
    return View();
}

//This action return a view that show the 402 http error captured.
public ActionResult Unauthorized()
{
    return View();
}
```

In the web.config file of my project:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/NotFoud" />
  <error statusCode="402" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/Unauthorized" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

**NOTE: Change the URL with your CustomURL desired.**

Help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx